# ManagedService won't get called from File Install

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have a Felix setup like this:

```
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.0.1)
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.4)
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.8.8)
    3|Resolved   |    1|Apache Felix File Install (3.5.0)
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.14.0)
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.16.2)
    6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
    7|Active     |    1|g.db OSGi Bundle (1.0.0)
```

The `g.db` bundle does basically this:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator, ManagedService {

ServiceRegistration sr;

public void updated(Dictionary dict) throws ConfigurationException {
    System.err.println("\nupdated " + this);
}

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

    System.err.println("\nstart " + this);

    Dictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props.put(Constants.SERVICE_PID, "db");
    sr = context.registerService(ManagedService.class.getName(), this, props);

}
}
```

And I'm awaiting that `updated()` get called if I modify `db.cfg` in `./load`. But it won't.

```
g! inspect cap service 7
g.db [7] provides:
------------------------------------
service; org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService with properties:
   service.bundleid = 7
   service.id = 28
   service.pid = db
   service.scope = singleton
```

File Install is watching the right file. I get the log message when modifying `db.cfg`:

```
Updating configuration from db.cfg
```

---

I raised the log level of the Configuration Admin Service and get this:

```
*DEBUG* Scheduling task Update: pid=db
*DEBUG* Running task Update: pid=db
*DEBUG* UpdateConfiguration(db) scheduled
*DEBUG* Updating configuration db to revision #3
*DEBUG* No ManagedService[Factory] registered for updates to configuration db
```

Seems something is wrong with my service registration (?)

---

**Finally** it was an error in the POM of the NB project: I was using the `org.osgi.compendium` artifact in `compile` scope. Changing to `provided` scope and it works.

Comment: check if you don't have multiple configurations under this pid, one managed by fileinstall, and the one injected into the service. fileinstall search first a configuration linked to the file, and then ask the configuration with a pid

Comment: What does your Manifest contain?

Comment: @Christian good point ! I messed it up there. Thank you !

Comment: Would be great if you could document what you did wrong and how you fixed it. Maybe it can help somone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile or provided scope should normally make no difference... unless you also embed all compile scope dependencies.

In this case the error you had is normal as you embed the spec package. So the package your bundle sees and the package the config admin service uses are different. So your ManagedService will not be picked up by the config admin service impl.